# Как сделать напротив текста ввода в input крестик, при нажатии на который контенты бы сразу удалялся?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

Как сделать напротив текста ввода в input крестик, при нажатии на который контенты бы сразу удалялся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать это очень просто:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.group>label').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().val('');
  });
});
```

```css
label{
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <label>x</label>
  <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
</div>
```

Не знаю что объяснить в этом коде, просто обрабатываем нажатие клик на `label`, в котором наш крестик, и убираем текст следующей за ним тега `input`. Вам нужно только стилизовать крестик так как будет угодно.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ был полезен для меня:)